# Working on Flask to get List of int and return those values as endpoint

Tags: python, flask, redis, redis-py

I want to use Flask in such a way where I can simply pass use localhost/data/?user=[123,234,345] and it will return those values in the body.

This is what I've tried:

```
import redis 
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
@app.route('/data', methods=['GET','POST']) 
def data():
    user = request.args.getList('user', type=int)
    users = []

    for u in user:
        try:
            users.append(redisfunction(u)) 
        except:
            continue

    return users
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `request.args.getList` should be `request.args.getlist`, lowercase of l, or it will cause error code 500, the reason I'm not find now
2. you should visit `localhost/data?user=123&user=234&user=345`

here is my simpe code:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
    user = request.args.getlist('user', type=int)
    print user
    return 'done'

app.run()
```

then `curl 'localhost:5000/data?user=123&user=234&user=345'`

**flask output**:

[123, 234, 345]

127.0.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2016 09:23:48] "GET /data?user=123&user=234&user=345 HTTP/

Comment: args is MultiDict object which only has getlist function. http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict

Comment: @LeonF Yes, it only has getlist function. But use getList doesn't cause an exception. I think maybe  the internal of Flask just throw a 500 error code when not found this method.

Comment: @KaiWen it only seems to return 'done', but I want to return the list. I tried return users, but it threw me an error `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: @AugmentedJacob You can not return an object, `from flask import json` then `return json.dumps(users)`